# High CPU load while IDLE

Tags: ubuntu, central-processing-unit, raid1

I have a little issue with CPU load on an ubuntu server 16.04. In IDLE is still: load average: 1.05, 1.06, 1.11. Processes, which are the biggest consumers of resources are md126_raid1 and md126_resync. Of course, on HDD is no activity.

Mountpoint of this drive is:

```
/dev/md126      2.7T   74M  2.6T   1% /mnt/data0
```

Raid1 is via raid integrated in Motherboard MSI H170M PRO-VDH, CPU is Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G4400 @ 3.30GHz.

Some idea, what can be a case of this issue? or is just something like "tax" for using integrated raid solution on this Motherboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `md126` device indicates that you are using Linux software RAID on the server.

The `resync` process indicates that it is syncing the two drives in the RAID1 setup. Load average over 1 means that the resync process is using one CPU completely for the resync.

You can run `cat /proc/mdstat` to see the progress of the resync.

Once the resync is finished, CPU load will go back to close to zero.